# jQuery - Error in parsing in JSON

Tags: jquery, json

I am using the method `$.parseJSON(msg);` to parse JSON string. The JSON String is :

```
{"userSearch": [{"path":"/content/odin/en/optum/secure/learn-base/getting-started/quickpick-persona","date":"October 08 2014"},{"path":"/content/odin/en/optum/secure/learn-base/getting-started","date":"October 20 2014"},] }
```

But it is not resolving the json string. Any pointers ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Trailing comma at the very end.  JSON is very strict - you should always let a machine encode it for you.

Comment: Already tried removing the comma at the end but it doesn't work.

Comment: If the comma isn't the only issue, can you please provide some more context? How is `msg` being defined? Are you receiving any particular errors? Can you create [an example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: Are you sure you are passing in a string to parseJSON?  I just tried your above code in the console and it worked (remove the extra comma, wrap it in single quotes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$.parseJSON() requires you to pass in a **string** of JSON. So, you need to surround your json with single quotes.

`$.parseJSON('{"userSearch": [{"path":"/content/odin/en/optum/secure/learn-base/getting-started/quickpick-persona","date":"October 08 2014"},{"path":"/content/odin/en/optum/secure/learn-base/getting-started","date":"October 20 2014"}] }');`

works.

Note, you had a trailing comma after the `"October 20 2014"}` - that also made your passed in json string invalid and caused errors.

Source: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/

Comment: Thanks for your inputs the string above is working fine when I provide it directly inside parseJSON() method. But when the same string is fetched through an ajax call, it is throwing error unexpected token. I have confirmed and the Json string formed is exactly same.

Comment: jsonDataString ="\'{"+ "\"userSearch\""+":"+" "+"["+jsonDataString+"]"+" "+"}\'"; That's how I am forming the JSON.

Comment: It looks like jsonDataString is being initialized and referenced in this same line. (Of course, I'm not sure what you had it originally set to.) My suspicion is it's not returning what you expect, and the string it's trying to parse looks like this: `'{"userSearch": [undefined] }'`. That is invalid json, hence the error.

Answer (score -1):

You have an extra comma at the end of the line. Remove that and it should work fine.

Comment: Already tried removing the comma at the end but it doesn't work.